# Create an 'Open URL' Mac OS X keyboard shortcut via a Service in Python program?

Tags: python, macos, service, keyboard-shortcuts

Summary. I want to create an ['Open URL' Mac OS X keyboard shortcut](http://bit.ly/macos-mavericks-OpenURL-keyboard-shortcut) in a Python program. This keyboard shortcut open's any URL's found in any currently-selected text. Enables the user to not have to laboriously "copy and paste" every selected URL into a different web-browser tab.

I'm guessing this requires "calling" said Mac OS Service, but I'm not sure. How to do this? [MacVim](http://bit.ly/MacVim-OpenURL-shortcut) and many other programs already do this: http://bit.ly/MacVim-OpenURL-shortcut

Details:

The few [Mac OS X Service programming docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html) I see appear complex, with few in any examples for what I seek, and appear to focus more on *creating* the service. Hard to tell since it seems to cryptic. I'm hoping that "calling" the service (or whatever) is relatively simple.

My background: I used to be an experienced C/C++/etc and Linux/etc sysadmin in a past life. Now I'm more of a "business" person / MacOS superuser who hacks up Python scripts when other team resources are not available. Therefore, I'm not looking to become an expert in "MacOS system programming."  Rather, with this question, I'm focusing on adding the above small feature to an existing, Python-based program.

Comment: Use `automator.app`. It should already be in your applications folder. And if you want to call something that you can already do in something (say like a shell), you can use `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Thanks, but how, exactly? I want to call the 'Open URL' (see above) keyboard shortcut from my Python program. I don't see an obvious way to do this in from `Automator.app` per the docs that I see.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood. You want to basically use that shortcut for use in a python program?

Comment: I think so. In any case, implement this Service/Keyboard Shortcut like MacVim and other programs do: http://bit.ly/MacVim-OpenURL-shortcut

Comment: I just saved an edit to the question further describing what the 'Open URL' shortcut does, and why it's useful.